# A decision making probability question

Tags: probability

I have a problem that goes like this:

"At a certain company, the decision making follows the next scheme:
Every proyect proposal first goes to A. If he aproves it, the proposal goes to  B, C and D. If B or D approve it, the proposal goes to E. If E or C approve the proposal, it goes to F. The proposal is accepted only if it reaches F and She approves it.
The probability that A, C, and F aproving a proposal is 0.5, ahíle the probability of B,D and E aproving a proposal i.   s 0.7. Also, the decisions taken by A, B, C, D, E and F aré independent. 
A) What is the probability that a certain proposal is approved?
B) If a proyect is aproved, which is the probability that it goes through E?
C) if a proyect is approved, which is the probability that it goes through C and he approves it?"

I defined an event S: "the proposal is approved" , and observed that there are three possible ways to get through S. So i defined another 3 events:
C1: A -> C -> F,
C2: A -> B -> E -> F,
C3: A -> D -> E -> F,

Is it Ok to say that P(S) = P(C1 U C2 U C3)?

After that, I calculated P(C1) = P(F|C|A) = P(F)P(C)P(A) (because the events are independent), but then, P(c1) = 1.5, which i don't like, because 1.5>0. Same thing happens When i calculate P(c2)' and P(c3)...

P(C1 U C2 U C3) = P(C1)  + P(C2) + P(C3) - P(C1 Int C2) - P(C1 Int C3) - P(C2 Int C3) + P(C1 Int C2 Int C3) = P(C1)  + P(C2) + P(C3), because, as I understand, C1, C2 and C3 are mutually exclusive events. This would make the probability greater than 0. I would appreciate that You make me know What kind of lies i'm making, or guise me a little bit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many of us will recognize that the problem is about our university?

Comment: Why are C1, C2, and C3 mutually exclusive?  Can't B,C,D, and E all approve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  $C_1$ requires three events to all happen, so it is the product, not the sum, of the probabilities of each event.  That will solve your probability being greater than $1$.  It is OK to say $P(S) = P(C1 \cup C2 \cup C3)$, but the events are not mutually exclusive so you can not just add the probabilities of the three.  You have to have $A$ and $F$, so you can distribute them out and multiply them by the probability that at least one of your inner chains approves.

Comment: So is it ok to say that P(C1 int C2) = P(A)P(F)[P(C) + P(B)P(E)]?

Comment: No.  One fix would be to make the + an int.  I am not sure that helps.  Another fix would be to make it union, not int on the left.  In that case, on the right the + should be union because it is possible that B,C,E all approve.  To use + you need to make sure the possibilities are exclusive.

Comment: Do You mean that P(C1 int C2) = P(A)P(F)[P(C int (B intE)] ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  To get both C1 and C2, you need all of A,F,C,B,E